# how to do $_POST for datepicker in php/codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

First, I'm using the codeigniter framework and I'm a beginner in JS and AJAX, so please bear with me.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923264/how-to-pass-the-jquery-datepicker-value-in-form-post-method)  question, so I tried to follow the answers.

This is the script **(UPDATED)**:

```
 $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker").datepicker().click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>backend/umat/add",
                dataType: "json",
                data: $('#form_daftar').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("Done");

                }
            });
            return false;
            });
        });
```

And this is my datepicker HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"
value="<?php echo isset($umat['tanggal_lahir'])?$umat['tanggal_lahir']:""?>"/>
```

My questions are **(UPDATED)**:

1. Is the URL I provided in AJAX above correct?
2. How should I pass the data from AJAX to PHP (`url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>backend/umat/add"`)?

Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 2):

What you have missed here:

1. your click event is outside of the doc ready handler, that should be inside doc ready so that when page gets ready the element should be available to click.
2. You have missed a closing `});` tag of the click event.(*does not matter though*)

so try this:

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker").datepicker();

        $("#datepicker").click(function() {
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>backend/umat/add",
              dataType: "json",
              data: {frmData : $('#form_daftar').serialize()}, // <----send this way
              success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data.date);
                  // here data is the returned data from the specified url and make sure
                  // that url is generating a proper json structrue.
                  // suppose there is a key named date which holds the submitted date so
                  // data.date will get you the date.
              }
           });
        }); //<----you missed this closing of click function.
    }); //<----------put everything before this closing of doc ready handler.
```

Although you can chain it too like this:

```
$(function(){
   $( "#datepicker").datepicker().click(function() {
       //......ajax function in click here
   });
});
```

[**See a demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/t6nJP/)

Comment: Are you sure you can chain it? I think `.datepicker()` returns the datepicker object, not the jQuery object.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst [**See a demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/t6nJP/) datepicker and click event both with chaining.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the calendar is working again. Please see my updated question :D

Comment: @BlazeTama you are not sending an object to the url try this `{data : $('#form_daftar').serialize()}` because you are using json so this should be in format of json this way. try this and see if helps.

Comment: @Jai Thanks for your help. How to retrieve the data? im kind of blind to AJAX and JS :(

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst See json is a key value pairs kind of stuff, so you need to see which string key is holding the date value and you can do one thing in the `success:function(){}` see in the answer i am updatding currently.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use the datepicker inbuilt methods to trigger ajax request like

```
$('#datepicker').datepick({
      dateFormat:"yyyy-mm-dd",
      onSelect:function(){
          $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: "<?php echo site_url('backend/umat/add'); ?>",
             dataType: "json",
             data: $('#form_daftar').serialize(),
             success: function(data) {
                 console.log("Done");
             }
          });                                   
      }
});
```

Check the manual or inbuild functions and callbacks with your datepicker js.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the calendar is working again. Please see my updated question :D

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
$(function() {
            $( "#datepicker").datepicker();         
            $("#datepicker").change(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>backend/umat/add",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: $('#form_daftar').serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("Done");

                    }
            });
        });
```

php get data form ajax:

```
<?php
$date = $_POST["datepicker"];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the calendar is working again. Please see my updated question :D