# using the getDate function for JQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Hi :) Sorry if my question sounds a bit stupid but I am not the most experienced with javascript..

I have done the code to have a JQuery Datepicker calendar displayed on my page and that works fine. But I want to store the date which is selected in a variable called $HistoryDate..I have put the following code between the  tags;

```
    <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

I have looked up the getDate function and Im guessing its something along the lines of;

```
var HistoryDate;
         HistoryDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
```

Im tried that method, by putting the above two lines in the head tags aswell but when I try echo HistoryDate() in the body I get nothing? Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show how you echo HistoryDate() in the body?  Are you including both jquery and jquery ui?

Answer (score 0):

```
var HistoryDate;
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(){ 
            HistoryDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: This looks similar to what I was thinking but how do I call the javascript variable HistoryDate in php? Sorry again if my questions sound ridiculous..

Comment: @user3266484 If your datepicker is a part of a form, you don't need a javascript "historyDate" variable. You have an input with an id, which you can get as as POST variable in php.

Comment: It's not possible. Or if you want use Ajax, to send the variable to au php page. (If the answer help you, vote up and check resolved)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I tried the POST method to begin with as I am well used to using that but when I assigned $HistoryDate = $_POST['datepicker']; I got nothing?

Comment: @user3266484 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923264/how-to-pass-the-jquery-datepicker-value-in-form-post-method

Comment: Thanks, I found out what it was..just a bit of code in the wrong place. I just spent hours thinking it was something big. Oh well, thanks a million for all ye're help!